# Binding a knockout selects value to a key/value array

Tags: knockout.js

I am having some trouble trying to use knockout binding to a select.

The data I am trying to bind against looks like

```
{
  "SomeProperty": 1,
  "Attributes": [
    {
      "name": "EmailId",
      "value": "1111"
    },
    {
      "name": "Something",
      "value": "223"
    },
    {
      "name": "SomethingElse",
      "value": "19999"
    },
    {
      "name": "IsActive",
      "value": true
    }
  ],
}
```

My select is binding correct to the datasource and I am getting the options populated correctly

```
<select class="form-control"
                data-bind="options: $root.types,
                optionsText: 'Key',
                optionsValue: 'Value',
                // value:1111,
                value: $root.helperText($data.Attributes(), 'EmailId'),
                optionsCaption: 'Please Select...'">
        </select>
```

Finally my helper to try set the selected value looks like

```
   self.helperText = ko.computed({
                read: function(attributesToSearch, idToSearchBy) {
                    debugger
                    return "";
                },
                write: function(attributesToSearch, idToSearchBy){ 
                    if (attributesToSearch != undefined) {
                        debugger
                        $.grep(attributesToSearch, function(e) {
                            if (e.name() == idToSearchBy) {
                                return e.value();
                            }
                            return null;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Now I don't get any issues and the codes logic seems to work correct however no value is returned.

I have tried

```
<span data-bind="value:$root.helperText($data.Attributes(), 'EmailId')"></span>
```

However neither return anything, am I doing something stupidly wrong here?

Any help would be very helpful

Comment: can you make us a fiddle with your issue . one thing i didn't get here is why your value binding is like that for drop-down cant you simply capture the selected value i.e `value:$data.someobservable`

Comment: You can't use a `computed` like that. The `read` function should be one without parameters, and the `write` function should be one with only one parameter (the new value). Check out [this part of the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html).

Comment: At any rate, to be able to help you I have to second @supercool: we need a repro, or at least the code for your view model. Preferably create a Stack Snippet (it's on the editor toolbar) to reproduce your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

- You are binding `value` to a `<span>` element, while it is only meant for form elements.
- A `computed` is not a function that you can execute with whatever parameters you wish. It is tied to one or more other observables *defined inside the constructor/ object*.
- For `writable computed`'s the **read** function returns the *displayed output* of a binding, and your `read` function returns `''`, so that of course, you don't see a value.

  The **write** function is the function which can be passed **1** parameter `value`, usually bound to a form element, that will change the original observable the computed is tied to.

For example, a while ago, I was wondering how a `<textarea>` could serve to input an option list (with every new line being an option), with validation, and without creating separate observables for the view. Here is a good example of using a writable computed in a component:

http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/8ht5zg2c/1/